# Non-EU visiting UK together with EU spouse and UK marriage certificate

Tags: visas, uk, russian-citizens, spouses, weddings

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen

> **Implementation in the United Kingdom**
>
> As of 6th April 2015, the non-EU
>   family members of an EU national who are in possession of a residence
>   card, which is issued to them under article 10 of directive 2004/38,
>   are entitled to enter the UK without the need to apply for an EEA
>   Family Permit, only by providing their residence card at the border.
>   However, the UK border officers would grant entry to non-EU family
>   members if they can prove their relation to the EU national family
>   member who would be accompanying them, by providing documents such as
>   marriage or birth certificate.

Does it mean, if I have a UK marriage certificate and EU spouse traveling with me, I can visit UK without visa ? (I'm Russian with Swedish permanent residency)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be able to present a marriage certificate **together with this article 10 residence card** (that's the same thing than the “residence card for a family member of an union citizen“ you asked about with respect to Ireland). Even if it's not very clearly written, that's what the Wikipedia text means and the [official gov.uk website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card) is very clear about it.

So you cannot (easily) reach and enter the UK with the marriage certificate only. If you don't have the right type of residence card, you are supposed to get a visa (see also [Will a non-EU citizen get stamped with a family permit at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68434/will-a-non-eu-citizen-get-stamped-with-a-family-permit-at-the-airport)).

Comment: My Swedish residency card, I got as reunion with my Swedish wife. But the card doesn't say anything about "family member". So, will it be ok, if I travel with my wife, our UK issued married certificate, her Swedish and my Russian passport, plus my Swedish residency card, which issued for me because I married to swedish, but doesn't state that on the card :)

Comment: Relaxed: I believe you have mischaracterized the quoted text: the article 10 card suffices without the certificate. @ViacheslavBakshaev: in theory you can get in without the visa but in practice it will be difficult because your card is not an article 10 card. The visa, called *EEA family permit,* is free of charge, so why not just apply for one?

Comment: @phoog because I need to go to another city to apply for it, takes time and money. How to get this article 10 card? :)

Comment: @ViacheslavBakshaev You cannot easily get one in your situation.

Comment: @phoog I would expect it to be that way but I just read the gov.uk page once again and I don't think I am mischaracterizing it. See section 3 (“Evidence you need to bring in addition to your residence card”), it reads "In order to be admitted to the UK, we would expect to see the following in addition to your valid residence card: […] evidence that you are the family member of an EEA national (for example, your marriage certificate or birth certificate)”.

Comment: So, I have a permanent residency card an I can travel with it to all countries in Schengen Area, but even if I go with my wife and UK issued married certificate, I still can't enter UK, as my residency card should be issued not in Sweden (as I'm married to Swedish).. because it's under the local Swedish low.. Though I received this card outside of EU, I couldn't apply for it in Sweden.. that was EU law.. but I might be wrong..

Comment: @ViacheslavBakshaev Not sure I fully understand your comment but this is a card you can only get if you and your wife live together in another EU country (i.e. not in Sweden and not outside of the EU but for example in France, Germany, etc.) Conversely the spouse of citizens from other EU country can get it in Sweden (so a Russian citizen living with his German wife in Sweden would have such a residence card). Does it clarify things?

Comment: Basically (apart from some very specific cases), your wife isn't considered as an EU citizen in her own country. So everything you read about EU citizens and their family does not apply to you while you are in Sweden.