# After EEA family permit refusal, will we be allowed in the UK as tourists?

Tags: uk, europe, visa-refusals, eu, application-status

We're in Brazil, planning a trip to the UK. I have a Portuguese passport as well, and have been living and working the UK for the past 5 years. I came to Brazil 2 years ago for work and kept going back and forth. UK-Brazil.

I got married in Brazil in this period. Now my work in Brazil is done and I want to go back to the UK, initially for a short trip (3-4 weeks) and, if all goes well, we'll move back permanently. I understood the best route at the moment is to apply for an EEA family permit.

We've applied for that permit, it's been refused, claiming that we didn't provide enough proof that we had a genuine relationship. We've added more proof and re-submitted the application and now are waiting for the results.

In case that's refused as well, I'm considering what other options we have to visit the UK.

1. If we go after a second refusal, will she be stopped in the border when she tries to enter as a tourist? The goal of the trip is to see what she thinks about the country and if we really would like to stay there.
2. If she would be denied entry, what other options do we have other than to keep applying for an EEA family permit to take this short trip to the UK?

I'm asking these, ignoring the fact that the UK is leaving the EU because, as far as I know, there hasn't been any changes to these procedures yet. I'm aware they are about to change.

Comment: How long after your marriage did you apply? There are a lot of improper refusals of EEA family permits.

Comment: What passport does your partner hold?

Comment: I've also read of couples being admitted under the EEA immigration rules by immigration officers after being denied an EEA family permit. It must have been in a comment, because I can't find it by searching either here or on [expatriates.SE]. If your partner is a non-visa national, or if you can get into France, Belgium, the Netherlands or Ireland, this might be an option for you.  But it's also possible to get a Standard Visitor Visa after an EEA FP refusal, at least in theory.

Comment: @phoog about 5 months after the marriage day

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul she holds a noon EU passport, Brazilian.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm definitely anxious, and I understand why this could be closed as opinion-based, if there is no right answer, we'll only know after we try and even if we pass others might not. However regardless of my second application being refused or not, there will be someone else on a similar case looking for answers and I believe if we can compile information here that would be useful for them as well.

Comment: @phoog I remember that too.

Comment: @phoog Maybe [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77492/non-eu-visiting-uk-together-with-eu-spouse-and-uk-marrige-certificate)?

Comment: @GayotFow point taken. Fingers crossed it will be approved.

Comment: @mkennedy I specifically remember the traveler saying that the IO reacted in some way to imply or perhaps state that the FP refusal had been improper, but I don't see that on the page you link to.

Comment: @GayotFow I have of course seen those, but I do not understand your point in mentioning them now. By "improper refusals" I mostly mean those that say "it is reasonable to expect evidence that your relationship is genuine" when this is entirely contrary to the policy that the ECO has to meet a burden of proof before suspecting a marriage of convenience.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm hoping to convey the idea that not all decisions need to be taken at face value, and that's especially likely to be the case when the relationship is being questioned, as OP indicated has happened here. Whether the refusal is in fact improper in this case I have no idea.

Comment: Would not be easier to legalize the marriage in Portugal so she has a PT passaport as well?

Comment: Not sure what's the best practice here, @GayotFow you perhaps may be able to help. This second resubmission was successful, a few days ago we got the response. I answered my own question down there based on your comments. I think it's best to leave it like this instead of deleting the question but voting to close it makes sense to me.

Comment: +1 for your answer, looks ok, an answer that explains the question is indeterminate is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As GayotFow mentioned in his comment, my question is impossible to answer. There isn't a defined rule that we can check to decide on that, each individual case will have it's own answer, the grounds for refusal will be different in each application and therefore could be questioned, or not, by the border control.